# Implementar Filtro de Seguridad API REST - CORS - Spring Framework 4.1

Tags: java, api, spring, rest

Estoy tratando de implementar seguridad por URL a mi API REST,ES DECIR QUE SOLO PUEDA REALIZARSE PETICIONES DESDE UN DOMINIO ESPECIFICO, las soluciones que encuentro en linea me indican que utilice @CrossOrigin pero el proyecto en el cual estoy trabajando tiene el SPringFrameWork 4.1, y las soluciones con @CrossOrigin estan disponibles a partir de la version 4.2 de SpringFrameWork.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has considerado actualizar el framework?

Answer (score 1):

En principio no debería ser un cambio muy traumático de la 4.1 a la 4.2, pero si por algún motivo no puedes hacerlo, siempre puedes utilizar un filtro.

Mete esto en web.xml (te sugiero que el url-pattern lo modifiques para que afecte sólo a las llamadas que te interese, por ejemplo /rest/*

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GlobalFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>calabacin.controller.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GlobalFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Y luego crea la clase CorsFilter para que modifique la respuesta en los casos especificados en el url-pattern del web.xml

```
public class GlobalFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Establece aquí la cabecera que quieras
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter();
    }
}
```